# Which countries have significant magical populations?

Tags: harry-potter, wizards, geography

While the Harry Potter books are primarily set in Great Britain, there are various references to wizards from other countries.

### Which countries do we know to have significant magical populations?

Any level of canon is acceptable, but Rowling-canon is preferred.

Comment: Good question. Also, do the boundaries between national wizarding governments correspond to muggle political boundaries? And if so, how does that come about? Are the wizarding boundaries changed accordingly every time the muggle boundaries change as a result of war, secession, or merger?

Comment: @user14111 Another good question. Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113033/is-ireland-independent-in-harry-potter

Comment: Significant to what? The stories? The UK, France, Bulgaria, Ireland, Albania, Egypt, wherever Grindelwald was from… and that’s about it, as far as I can recall. The rest probably have magical communities of varying sizes, but they’re not significant to the books.

Comment: Can you clarify what "significant" means ? As % of the total population of the country or as an absolute number? Could be something else of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as we know all countries have a wizarding population, and they all appear to have a proportionate wizarding population. We are not lead to believe that any country DRAWS in more wizards then normal. i guess in theory the old world probably has a few more old pureblood families then the new world simply by traditional movement patterns.

> Bill had a penfriend at a school in Brazil . . . this was years and
>   years ago . . .  and he wanted to go on an exchange trip but Mum and
>   Dad couldn’t  afford it.

---

> He supposed, now that he saw rep- resentatives of so many
>   nationalities in the campsite, that he had  been stupid never to
>   realize that Hogwarts couldn’t be the only  one. He glanced at
>   Hermione, who looked utterly unsurprised by  the information. No doubt
>   she had run across the news about  other wizarding schools in some
>   book or other.

**US**

> while a group of middle-aged
>   American witches sat gossiping happily beneath a spangled banner 
>   stretched between their tents that read: the salem witches’ 
>   institute. Harry caught snatches of conversation in strange lan-
>   guages from the inside of tents they passed, and though he couldn’t 
>   understand a word, the tone of every single voice was excited.

**France**

> “They must go to Beauxbatons,” said Hermione. “You know . . .
>   Beauxbatons Academy of Magic . . . I read about it in An Appraisal  of
>   Magical Education in Europe.”

**Ireland**

> You’ll be supporting Ireland, of course?” she added, eye- ing Harry,
>   Ron, and Hermione beadily.

**Africa** (yes continental via state)

> Three African wizards sat in serious conversation, all
>   of them wearing long white robes and roasting what looked like 
>   a rabbit on a bright purple fire

**Egypt**

Bill works for Gringotts as a curse breaker, and works in Egypt were the ancient Egyptian wizards set up complex curses to protect tombs.

**Bulgaria**

> Harry — DAD GOT THE TICKETS — Ireland versus  Bulgaria, Monday night.
>   Mum’s writing to the Muggles to ask you to stay. They might already
>   have the letter, I don’t know  how fast Muggle post is. Thought I’d
>   send this with Pig  anyway.

This exhaustive list of quidditch teams also indicates large magical population

[Teams:D](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Quidditch_teams)

Comment: Any evidence for "**significant** magical populations" in these countries?

Comment: @randal'thor still going, but mostly big enough to feild national level quiditch teams

Comment: aka the reason the US always wins the olymipcs other then money, is because of population size, so if counties like bulgaria can field a worlds level quidditch team they have to have a sizable population.

Comment: I'm not going to get into a debate on why the US wins the Olympics ... too much cynicism and not enough knowledge :-)

Comment: @randal'thor uk wins lots of medials being a tiny country, it all comes down to money irl, but population size helps to get good people to then pay to be amazing

Comment: Can you fix the hyphenation pasted in the quotes please?

Answer (score 6):

All of the below have Quidditch teams of their own. So, they would have atleast a large enough magical population:

Argentina

Armenian junior

Australia

Africa

> Has the Uagadou School of Magic

Brazil

Bulgaria

Burkina Faso

Canada

Chad

China

Cote d'Ivoire

England

Egypt

> In GoF, the Quidditch referee [Hassan Mustafa](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Hassan_Mostafa) is Egyptian
>
> The third book talks about the powerful wizards of Egypt, who have put
>   those powerful spells/charms on the pyramids.

Fiji

Flanders

France

> Has the Beauxbatons Academy of Magic. Mentioned in the fourth book
>   (Goblet of Fire)

Germany

> Crest of the German Quidditch team:
>
> [image]

India

Ireland

> Mentioned a lot of times in the GoF book. And witches like Pansy
>   Parkinson, the Patil sisters, etc all hail from Ireland. So, it must
>   have a considerable magical population.
>
> Crest of the Irish quidditch team:
>
> [image]

Italy

Jamaica

Japan

> Has the Mahoutokoro school of magic (Mentioned in the  Wonderbook:
>   Book of Potions)

Liechtenstein

Luxembourg

Madagascar

Malawi

Mexico

Moldova

Morocco

New Zealand

Nigeria

The Nordic team

> Crest of the Nordic Quidditch Team:
>
> [image]

Norway

Peru

Poland

Portugal

Romania

> Charlie Weasley is said to be studying dragons in Romania.

Russia

> Has the Koldovstoretz school of magic

Scotland

> Has the Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry

Senegal

Spain

> Crest of the Spanish Quidditch Team:
>
> [image]

Syria

Transylvania

Turkey

Uganda

United States of America

> Crest of the US Quidditch Team:
>
> [image]

Wales

---

Source: [Potter Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/)

Comment: Where do the crests come from?

Comment: @ibid  From the [Potter wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Quidditch_teams).  To be noted that some teams like China, India, etc are recently added from PotterMore :)

Comment: Do they have a source? I don't think the crests were in QttA.

Comment: @ibid I guess they were listed from the movie scenes!

Comment: @ibid Nope, from PotterMore. The crest might have been an adaption by an artist in PM!

Comment: [The old Pottermore](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-8DzVlCskQCk/U5cZWEDgRlI/AAAAAAAAFFI/m9Cbo8m2iZQ/s1600/Japan+vs.+Nigeria+Result.png) only used the country flags. If it's from the new Pottermore, you should be able to provide a link.

Comment: @ibid Couldn't find one. But, [here's](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Quidditch_teams) the link from where I got the images of the crests!

Comment: Without a source wiki is meaningless

Comment: @ibid Yeah, you're right. But,those pics are just extras in the answer. So, shouldn't matter :)